# Android get current running application package name

Tags: android, package, android-context

I have below code which run correctly in Android 5.0 and 6.0 but if i am using this application to Android 4.4 device then application goes to crash. Please help me to solve the issue.
Below is my code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
     packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(1).processName;
 } else { 
     packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
 }
 Log.e("Package : ", "" + packageName);
```

Error showing like this,

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: com.keyboardsample, PID: 23694
>                                                                       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/png flg=0x1 pkg=com.keyboardsample (has clip) (has extras) }
>                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
>                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
>                                                                           at com.keyboardsample.PhotoActivity$1.onItemClick(PhotoActivity.java:80)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: what is log is printing for package name because logcat clearly stating that activity not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```